# PhpStorm autocomplete image name, attribute, width and height in .jade files

Tags: html, autocomplete, pug, phpstorm

In usual html I can set images name, attribute, width and height for tag img using autocomplete in phpstrom, how I can do this in .jade files ?

Answer (score 0):

In general tag completion [works since v5](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12874).

If you are asking if IDE can automatically insert required attributes then it will be [WEB-2160](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2160) -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: Yes, I need auto complete attribute value. For example, in html when I write attribute height="" then press CTRL + space and after that height of image automatically set up.